# How to detect tf/keras model objects automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm working on supporting automatic model detection/logging for Keras/Tensorflow models for our Machine learning platform https://iko.ai and I have some questions:

- What are the different ways we can define a tf/keras model ?

  1. `tf.keras.Model`
  2. `tf.Estimator`
  3. `tensorflow_estimator`
- Any other ways I'm not aware of? Why are there so many ways to do the same thing?
- What are the proper functions to save/load them?
- How could we differentiate TF/Keras model instances from other non-model objects? I want to be able to write a function that checks if an object is a TF/Keras model, something like

```py
def is_tf_or_keras_model(obj):
    # check somehow if the obj is a TF/Keras model
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regarding questions 1 and 2:**

Another way to represent a neural network model is by using `tf.keras.Sequential`. It allows you to easily create a model that follows a sequential structure, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# tf.__version__ == 2.4

model_seq = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_seq.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(64,1)))
model_seq.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu'))
model_seq.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model_seq.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
```

This is the same as using the `tf.keras` functional API. This allows to build more complex networks that do not follow a sequential structure, but of course you can build sequential models anyway:

```
i = tf.keras.Input(shape=(64,1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu')(i)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)
model_func = tf.keras.Model(inputs=i, outputs=x)
```

`tf.estimator.Estimator` is used to train prebuilt networks, so you only have to define some hyperparameter values and train out of the box model.

In conclusion, the method used to build a model depends on how complex/ad-hoc the network is.

**Regarding question 3:**

The tf.keras implementation allows you to either save the weights of a model (`model.save_weights`) or save the whole model (`model.save`). To load the model weights afterwards you need to create the model first, following the same structure of the model used to train those weights.

**Regarding question 4:**

```
model_classes = [tf.keras.Model, keras.Model, tf.estimator.Estimator]

def is_keras_or_tf_model(obj, model_classes):
    return isinstance(obj, model_clases)
```

All I have said here is in the [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) documentation.

Comment: This is a great answer: it includes explanations, code, and links to documentation.  However, the **question itself does not meet SO guidelines** (StackOverflow.com/help). It is asking too many questions, *and* it's basically asking by for a tutorial, rather than a focusing on specific coding issue with a exact Answer. So, in this case, correct responses would include: 1) leave a comment to the OP, indicating how he could bring the question into compliance 2) flag the Q for closure as not meeting guidelines 3) leave your answer & doc links as a *Comment* 4) ignore this Q, answer a different Q